# Creating input form using Preference widgets in Android?

Tags: android, android-preferences

Anyone know how to create input form using preference widgets in Android?
Android's native alarm app has a "Set Alarm" form with Preference-like layout (see screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkkgN.png)), so I think it should be possible.

My plan is to derive a PreferenceActivity class, construct a set of Preference widgets, and disable each widget's persistency to avoid saving values in SharedPreference. However, I still don't know how to put "Save" and "Cancel" buttons at the bottom of the PreferenceScreen. It might be easier to layout if I use PreferenceFragment, but I still need to support minimum API level 8.

**Research update**: Adding "Save" and "Cancel" button to preference screen is possible via setListFooter method in PreferenceActivity class. However, this requires minimum API level 11.

[image: Android's alarm app input form]

Comment: what do you mean input? You can create a custom layout and inflate it in your preference activity. You can use a preference Fragment using v4 support and your app will accept API 8

Comment: User input. In the case of an Alarm app, the activity could be AddAlarmActivity and the user input would be alarm time, label, etc. In the custom layout, is it possible to use Preference widgets? Do I need to use PreferenceScreen container? Would be nice if you can point to an example. Thanks!